# How to use OpenSSL on node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, openssl

I'm using **twig js template for node js 13.6.0 with express 3.**

I'm trying to convert my php website to node js. In php, i used OpenSSL to crypt/decrypt user informations
and now i want to doo the same but in node js.

**Php function**

```
$secure_key= "Wzm7phmY8SwjtInXk1nY";//
$cipher = "AES-128-ECB";

function encrypt($pure_string, $encryption_key) {
    global $cipher;
    $encrypted_string = openssl_encrypt($pure_string, $cipher, $encryption_key);
    return $encrypted_string;
}

function decrypt($encrypted_string, $encryption_key) {
    global $cipher;
    $decrypted_string = openssl_decrypt($encrypted_string, $cipher, $encryption_key);
    return $decrypted_string;

}
```

i would like to do exactly the same function but for node.js

Please answer if you have any idea

Comment: The Node equivalent could be `crypto.createCipher('aes-128-ecb', key)`. The problem is that your key doesn't match the 128 bit key size and I don't know how createCipher() handles longer keys. Also, createCipher() is deprecated, and ECB is not that secure. If I were you, I would decrypt everything and then encrypt them with a stronger cipher.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `crypto` npm package. I guess this is cipher-salt encryption/decryption. So this should work.

```
function decrypt(password, saltHex, ivAndCipherTextHex) {
  const pass = Buffer.from(password, 'ascii');
  const salt = Buffer.from(saltHex, 'hex');
  const key = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(pass, salt, 1024, 32, 'sha1');
  const cipher = Buffer.from(ivAndCipherTextHex, 'hex');
  const iv = cipher.slice(0, 16);
  const cipherText = cipher.slice(16, cipher.length);
  const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);
  try {
    return Buffer.concat([
      decipher.update(cipherText),
      decipher.final(),
    ]).toString('utf8');
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(`Error during decrypt: ${err}`);
  }
}
```

Here is how to call this decrypt function.

> decrypt($secure_key, $salt, $cipher);

Comment: what is the salt??

Comment: I think `encryption_key` here is salt for you.

Comment: Can you also let me know what kind of encryption/decryption are you using ?

Comment: you mean the algorithm? It's openssl https://www.openssl.org/